# I would like to create an HTML table from multiple databases RoR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am fairly new to ruby of rails, but I would like to build this table from my MySQL database, consisting of two tables, Parents and Children.

```
enter code here
```

Children (:id, :name, :parentId)
Parent (:id, :name, :childId)

Here is the HTML code:

```
<% @children.each do |child| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= link_to child.name, child_path(child) %></td>
        <td><%= child.ticker %></td>
        <td><%= link_to child.parent, parent_path(parent) %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

The table would be able to link to the show path of both tables, but only when child.parentId = parent.id. The table is on my table page with controller

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def table
     @children = Child.all.order('name ASC')
          if params(:id) == child.parentId
              @parent = Parent.find(params[id])
          else
              @parent = NULL
          end
   end
end
```

I know this is incorrect, but I am struggling to create this table.  Any feedback or references are helpful!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `sqlite3`, then the database for your application should already be under db/development.sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve here, but perhaps I can help anyway. If I get it wrong, please feel free to correct me in the comments.

First, your `Parent` table does not need the `childId` column that I can see. Rails will still be able to tell which parents have which children, and which children belong to which parents, without it. I'd suggest getting rid of it.

As for the `Child` table, consider replacing `parentId` with `parent_id`. Rails uses the latter by default, and it's generally easier to just go with the default unless you have a good reason.

With these considerations in mind, your [migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) for these two models would probably look something like so:

**db/migrations/[timestamp]_create_parents.rb**

```
class CreateParents < ActiveRecord::Migration   
  def change
    create_table :parents do |t|

      # the id column is created automatically.
      t.string :name
    end
  end
end
```

**db/migrations/[timestamp]_create_children.rb**

```
class CreateChildren < ActiveRecord::Migration   
  def change
    create_table :children do |t|

      # this creates a column `parent_id` with a foreign key for enforcing
      # validity at the database level and an index for faster searching.
      t.references :parent, foreign_key: true, index: true

      t.string :name
    end
  end
end
```

You will want to [associate](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) these two models so that Rails can find the records that go together.

**app/models/parent.rb**

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  has_many :children

  ...
end
```

**app/models/child.rb**

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  belongs_to :parent

  ...
end
```

Now, I'm not quite sure what you mean to do in your controller action. To start, you could just write:

**app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def table
    @children = Child.all.order('name ASC')
  end
end
```

Make sure you have a [route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for this controller action. Then your view (slightly corrected below) ought to work, except perhaps for this `ticker` attribute. Is that something you have defined in your database table?

**app/views/static_pages/table.html.erb**

```
<table>
    <% @children.each do |child| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= link_to child.name, child_path(child) %></td>
            <td><%= child.ticker %></td> // as long as this attribute is defined, I believe it should work.
            <td><%= link_to child.parent.name, parent_path(child.parent) %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```